# Maximum drive size size (dimensions) that will fit in a Mac Mini Server 2012

Tags: hard-drive, mac-mini

I'm building up a few Mac Mini Servers (Late 2012). I will be upgrading the small internal drives (dual 500GB HDD) with either dual 4TB or 5TB Seagate Barracuda 2.5" drives, which are 2.75 x 3.95 x 0.59 in.

It appears these higher density drives are a little thicker (0.59") than common sizes sold as upgrade drives for a Mac Mini (0.276" - 0.374").

A [thread on the Apple Community](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4914104?tstart=0) suggests the largest size is 9.5mm (0.374").

Does anyone know the maximum drive dimensions that will fit in a Late 2012 Mac Mini Server?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, 9.5mm (0.374") is the [maximum size](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i5-2.5-late-2012-specs.html) that can be installed without modifications to the Mac. Bummer.